# WCF Service Reboot

Tags: .net, wcf

We have a simple desktop app consuming a WCF Service. Sometime we upgrade our desktop app and also the WCF service.  Upgrading wcf service is not a headache! But yes the desktop app.

Some users ignore our notification and never copy or install the latest desktop app. They keep running the old version of desktop app.

How can i figure out a WCF service has been rebooted, so that i can add version checking logic in one place and force users to copy the desktop app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is implement autoupdate feature in your application, you can implement from the ready made code given at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/CustomAppAutoUpdate.aspx?fid=431225&df=90&mpp=10&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Expanded&fr=11

when you update service you can put corresponding updated files on the web and your application will download the updates files.So the problem of version mismatch will never come.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep the Version number on the Service, and when the App tries to talk to the WCF the service checks the incoming desktop app version number and only process the request if the right version matches??

Comment: We do that... at the start up but avoided the versioning check in each of the exposed WCF calls.. is there any inbuilt mechanism to figure out! Anything available in pure remoting environment as well

Comment: To be honest i don't believe there is, reason mainly because its not like TCP where you check you send a message and receive a response and hold the connection.. BUT... just an idea, but you could on the Service possibly check the service setting on instantiation of the Service if you keep the service open for longer than one request.

Answer (score 0):

don't know it's possible in your case, but using ClickOnce deployment can add this requirement.

If ClickOnce is not possible, you can add in your service a version method to give app requirement, and in your application, either at startup or at scheduled interval, query this service and force the user to install the new app.

A more complex solution can also be investigated. You can code a "bootstrapper" application that will check the version app, install the new one if available and then only launch the actual app.

another option is to move to SilverLigth. I'm not sure it will apply as you are talking about a windows service option.

Finally you can take a look at the [Updater Application Block - Version 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff650611.aspx), which can put you on the track